# Rendering MathML in gmail & similar

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, gmail, equations

I am trying to generate inline equations in an email. I am composing in Outlook and using MathML, which appears as desired in Outlook itself. On testing, received email looks fine in Outlook, but in gmail, equations appear as image attachments - not inline as desired. I tried using Firefox Add-ons to compose in gmail in browser. They look fine in composition, but received email does not render properly.